# "Shoot in something" vs "shoot at something"

Tags: prepositions

Is there any difference between *shoot in something* and *shoot at something*? For example:

> The guy shot a few rounds **in**/**at** the car with a machinegun and ran away.

I have definetly heard native English speakers say *shoot in* something, but what is the difference betweeb *in* and *at* in the context. If there isn't any, which one is more common?

Comment: ***in*** is ambiguous in the cited context - did the shooter fire ***into*** the car (from somewhere outside), or ***out from*** the car (***in*** which they were)?

Comment: Yes, from outside. The car is the target in the context

Comment: Well, if you *know* that, just use ***into*** to make the intended sense crystal clear. (Or ***at*** if you want to be more vague as regards the shooter's accuracy! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the difference is whether you hit the target or not.

“shot into” tells you the the target was hit:

> he shot a dozen rounds into the car at close range

But “shot at” doesn’t say either way. It simply tells you shots were fired in that direction:

> he shot at the car as it sped past

Answer (score 0):

You shoot **in** a shooting range or in bad weather - or even into the air.

**In** describes the environment in which the shooting takes places.

You shoot **at** something, whether a target (such as a can or a bull's-eye) or a bird/animal as in hunting, or an enemy in battle.

Comment: You could shoot at a car, and the bullets, or some of them, might enter the car. If you shoot into a car, probably from close range, all of the bullets enter the car, and, possibly, its unfortunate occupants.

Comment: You could shoot the movie *in* 35 mm, or *in* 12-bit video, but "Its shot at 30 frames per second." sigh